# Natural key when combining two source tables that use similar promary keys

Tags: sql-server, etl, data-warehouse

I have two source tables, one is basically an invoice, the other is a migrated invoice. The same object should probably have been used for both, but I have this instead. They contain most of the same data.

I had thought to combine both into a dimension table, however both will use the same natural keys. How should I approach this?

One potential solution I thought of was using negative numbers for the migrated table, but then the natural keys won't align exactly with the source.

Do I just combine them in the fact table? Then I can't link back to the dimension table for either due to NULLs.

Or do I add an additional column or information to indicate which type of invoice it is?

EDIT

---

Simple models of the current tables below. 
The dimension currently only contains the non migrated data, it has a primary key, however 
if i merge the migrated invoice table in to this, it will appear as if the changes are being 
made to the original invoices and not a second set of invoices

Dimension

```
surrogate_key| source_pk | Total |  scd_from   | scd_to
             |           |       |             |
 1           | 1         | 100   | 01/01/2019  | 31/01/2019
 2           | 1         | 150   | 01/02/2019  | 31/12/2019
 3           | 2         | 50    | 01/01/2019  | 31/12/9999
```

source invoice table

```
pk         | Total
___________________
 1         | 150
 2         | 50
```

source migrated invoice table

```
pk         | total
___________________
 1         | 200
 2         | 300
```

Comment: Did you consider using an auto-increment non-business related number (aka IDENTITY)? You can keep the original invoice IDs but the new identity will be your primary key.

Comment: Updated information, apologies if I'm misunderstanding. I already have a surrogate PK on the dimension, but that won't help with the issue of duplicating natural keys

Comment: You can't keep keys from different systems on the same table without running into trouble. If these 2 represent completely different entities (that happen to share the same data) then you will need to differentiate in some way, maybe add another dimension for InvoiceSource or InvoiceOrigin and enforce uniqueness (if needed) by source_pk and InvoiceSourceID.

Comment: Could you add a "source_tbl" column and put I or MI in it to be an additional part of the natural key?

Answer (score 0):

If invoice and migrated invoice have same natural key but some of the fields have different values (your example shows Total amount different between them), then you have one row based on the natural key in the Dim but 2 different columns to represent the 2 sources. Based on your example, you need invoice_Total and migrated_invoice_Total columns in your DIM.

Comment: The problem is they represent two different objects, pk 1 of migrated invoice is unrelated to pk 1 of non-migrated invoice. Previously we would have migrated them into the same object type with a flag, but the dev team took a different approach this time. I think I'll just have to treat them as two different dimensions.